# How to block a wifi hotspot?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I'm seating in a public library located over a McDonalds, and every couple minutes I am kicked out of the free library wifi connection, and presented (on my browser) with the McDonalds wifi offer.

Is there a way for me to block the McD wifi from intruding like that?  Unfortunately, the McD network seem to be of greater strength, and right now I cannot move as all the tables in the library are taken...

Thanks,

JDelage

PS: Using Win XP and Firefox.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using the McD network while sitting in the library?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can add the public library wifi network to your preferred network list and move it up the priority list (higher than the mcdonald one)...

Answer (score 1):

The network isn't intruding; you have indicated you would be happy connecting to either (Windows XP remembers that you connected once, and assumes that you'd be happy to connect again). Use your wireless network utility to remove the entry for the undesired SSID.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on [about.com](http://antivirus.about.com/od/securitytips/ht/wirelessconn.htm) showing how to disable the auto-connect mechanism so you don't get bounced between connections.